# How to renew linkedin oauth access token using linkedin-j?

Tags: android, oauth, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I use LinkedIn-J lib to allow the users of my app to login to their LinkedIn account from within my app so that they can share posts from my app to LinkedIn. That all works great.

Now with the new LinkedIn policy where the access token expires in 60 days, LinkedIn recommends that apps should try to 'renew' the token within the 60 day period so that its completely transparent to the user and also there is no change in user experience.

Has anyone tried using the LinkedIn-J lib to renew the accesstoken before it expires? If yes, how would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

The 'expires_in' field value can be saved and you could schedule the renewal process accordingly.
I recently started using linkedin-j api, but POST/PUT methods weren't working with oAuth2.0. So had to switch back to oAuth1.0, wherein there is no problem of access token expiry.

Comment: princi, thanks for your response but I am not sure if that answers my question. i am aware of the 'expires_in' field but my question is about how to renew the token without bothering the user.